# Converting DateTime (DD MM YYYY HH MM SS) to Timespan like (DD MM YYYY HH MM SS) in c#

Tags: c#, datetime, string-formatting, timespan

Is it possible to exactly clone the DateTime value to Timespan data type. I converted the datetime to timespan by subtracting to min value. However, how do it display in DD MM YYYY HH MM SS format.

```
TimeSpan timeSpan = (DateTime)startTimeValue - DateTime.MinValue;
```

Comment: Why do you care about the amount of time that's passed since midnight of the first of january 1 AD? What you have there is a date and time, not a time-span, so why not use the DateTime type for it? Especially if you're going to convert it to a string anyway.

Comment: Perhaps you want to convert startTimeValue itself to 'DD MM YYYY HH MM SS' format and for that use startTimeValue.toString("dd MM yyyy HH mm ss"). If not please explain your requirement to make it more clear.

Comment: I have to insert datetime value in db, but the datatype in db is provided as Timespan. I can't modify db type now so trying to manupulate through code.

Comment: What database is it? Are you sure it wants a .NET timespan and not the number of ticks or seconds since an epoch?

Answer (score 0):

Little bit late but since you didn't get any attention, so..

> Is it possible to exactly clone the DateTime value to Timespan data
>   type

*Well*, since your example works exactly since `DateTime.MinValue` has `0` as a `Ticks`. It is equivalent to;

```
TimeSpan timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromTicks(((DateTime)startTimeValue)Ticks);
```

> how do it display in DD MM YYYY HH MM SS format

First of all, there is no `DD`, `YYYY` and `SS` as a [custom date and time format specifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). They are represented as `dd`, `yyyy` and `ss`.

`TimeSpan` is quite different than `DateTime`. It is a *time interval* but `DateTime` is a *point* in time. As you can see, a time interval can't have any month and year parts. In which `Calendar`? Not all calenders have 12 month. In which month exactly? How many months has 29 days are in `GregorianCalender`? Or `ChineseLunisolarCalendar`? It depends, right? Month and years concepts are ambigious for TimeSpan.

But *still*, you can format your `TimeSpan` as day, hour, minute and seconds with [`TimeSpan.ToString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992632%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method like;

```
timeSpan.ToString(@"d\.hh\:mm\:ss")
```

As a better alternative, you can use Nodatime which has [`Period`](http://nodatime.org/1.1.x/api/html/T_NodaTime_Period.htm) class and [`PeriodUnits`](http://nodatime.org/1.1.x/api/html/T_NodaTime_PeriodUnits.htm) enum that you can calculate these like;

```
using System;
using NodaTime;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        LocalDate start = new LocalDate(2010, 11, 20);
        LocalDate end = new LocalDate(2015, 7, 13);

        Period period = Period.Between(start, end, 
                                       PeriodUnits.Months | PeriodUnits.Years);

        Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", period.Months, period.Years); // 7 - 4
    }
}
```